# What is the purpose of a period directly after a forward slash?

Tags: python, unix, filesystems, os.path

Recently it was recommended that `os.path.expanduser(“~/.foldername”)` be used to access and write to a directory. After scanning some os.path tutorials, I couldn’t find anything explaining the function of the period after a forward slash. Was the period intended as part of the directory name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, it is intended as part of the directory name.**

On some file systems, a dot before a file or directory name denotes that the file or directory should be hidden from the user's view in the GUI.

For example, if you save a folder called `.foldername` in your user directory on most Unix-based operating systems and go to find it using a file explorer, you won't see it there.

This can be circumvented on [Mac OS](http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/) and many Linux distributions using various techniques for the operating system.

Comment: Change *most file systems* to *some file systems*. Also, Windows does not treat `.folder` any differently than any other folder; they're not hidden, and they're plainly visible in Explorer. (I have dozens of them created by Subversion named `.svn` that I see in Explorer.)

Comment: What if the dot precedes the forward slash ("./directoryname")?

Comment: @Phillip: That would indicate that `directoryname` is a directory under the working one. E.g. if I'm in `/Users/Bob/Documents` and I want to access `/Users/Bob/Documents/Work`, I could use the path `./Work` to get there.